# Changed text at the runtime in textview but after relaunching application retrieving default data in textview in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, textview

I am using Shared Preferences to store data which is came from `EditText` and set preferences data back to `TextView` but when i reopen my application textview shows default value. How can set changed data to the `TextView` and data should not be lost after reopening application. I tried `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` but this works when orientation change of application.

Here in my code i store data into shared Preferences and getting that data back to the `TextView` PRESET_MESSAGE_ONE i am storing value of `EditText`.

```
public void customDialogOne() {
    mDialog = new Dialog(_con);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_message);
    mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.black);
    mDialog.setTitle("Edit Preset Message");

    btnPresetDialogCancel = (Button) mDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnPrDialogCancel);
    edtPresetDialogMessage = (EditText) mDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.edtPrDialogMessage);

    btnPresetDialogSave = (Button) mDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnPrDialogSave);
    btnPresetDialogSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPref.writeString(SharedPref.PRESET_MESSGE_ONE,
                    edtPresetDialogMessage.getText().toString());
            msgOne = SharedPref.readString(SharedPref.PRESET_MESSGE_ONE);
            tm.showToast(msgOne);
            tvFrPresetMsgOne.setText(msgOne);
            mDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    btnPresetDialogCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: post your relevant code.

Comment: Please post your code. So i will provide you the solution of this problm

Comment: you need to put logic of resetting this value in the on resume of the relevant activity. onSaveInstanceState is only for orientation changes

Comment: Please let me know if any other way to achieve this task i am also looking for another solutions

Comment: you need to check it in `onResume()` method.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA can you please explain what should i check in onResume()?

Comment: @Reena can you post `SharedPref.writeString()` and `SharedPref.readString()` method source code?

Comment: @Reena After save your data in `SharedPreference` and while you are retrieving data from you need to retrieve it in `onResume()` method.

Comment: @Vandana Please have look at above two methods which i wrote in SharedPref static class
// for String value
 public static void writeString(String key, String value) {
  getEditor().putString(key, value).commit();

 }

 public static String readString(String key) {
  return getPreferences().getString(key, null);
 }

Comment: @Reena change this from `getPreferences().getString(key, null);` to `getPreferences().getString(key, "");`

Comment: @Piyush Thanks but solution is not that much helpful, i able to get data using getString(key,null), i am using this method to get and read data from server and its working, i think issue is at only TextView which is not able to set shared Preferences value after reopening the application.

Comment: @Reena Yes it is. But you have to retrieve your data in `onResume()` method. means call `SharedPref.readString()` in `onResume()` method.

Comment: Hi Friends my issue has resolved my sequence was wrong for storing value in shared preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has resolved my sequence was wrong to store value in shared Preferences, I used following code:

btnPresetDialogSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tvFrPresetMsgOne.setText(edtPresetDialogMessage.getText()
                    .toString());
            SharedPref.writeString(SharedPref.PRESET_MESSGE_ONE,
                    edtPresetDialogMessage.getText().toString());

            msgOne = SharedPref.readString(SharedPref.PRESET_MESSGE_ONE);
            tvFrPresetMsgOne.setText(msgOne);
            mDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

and read SharePreferences string in onResume method()

Answer (score 0):

Have you commit your changes in the SharedPreference using SharedPref.commit(); ? Please check that one.

Comment: public static void writeString(String key, String value) {
  getEditor().putString(key, value).commit();

 }